# Access a list in another project c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and am trying to create a list in one project and access the same in another project. Could you tell me what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are involved here:

1. Create a project, A in this case
2. Create a public class in project A, Foo in this case

   ```
   namespace A
   {
     public class Foo
     {
       // Empty
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create a public List inside of Foo, Bar in this case

   ```
   namespace A
   {
     public class Foo
     {
       public List<int> Bar;
     }
   }
   ```
4. Create a new project, B in this case
5. Reference project A from project B
6. Add the namespace to project A

   ```
   // From some class inside project B
   using namespace A;

   namespace B
   {
     public class Test
     {
       private Foo _foo;

       public Test()
       {
         _foo = new Foo();
         _foo.Bar.Add(1);
         _foo.Bar.Add(2);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Wrote this by hand, could be syntax errors, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Can you please clarify why this is "the best way" and in what way it actually better than other ways?

Comment: This is the only way you should be concerned with learning at the moment.

Comment: This explains it well, thanks a lot!!